# Aggregate a view with all controllers/views of MVC Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller

I have an MVC app with Node+Express+Mongo+Pug.
I have a bunch of independent controller+model+views working as desired (all forms which write to a mongo and print to view) [ lets call these items - stories, questions, reviews]
I now want to aggregate all of them and print them on a new page. I am getting confused on how to create this controller for this new page.

How should I go about this? I want to print a row of stories, questions and reviews in my homepage.
Example of what a single MVC looks like

controller1

```
const Story = require('../models/Story');

exports.getStories = (req, res, next) => {
  Story.find()
  .then((stories) => {
    res.render('story', {title:'StoryTata', stories});
  })
  .catch(() => { res.send('Sorry!'); });
  };
```

view1.pug for controller1

```
extends layout

block content
    body
        h1 #{title}
        if stories
            table
              tr
                th Title
                th Body
                th userName
              each story in stories
                tr
                  td= story.title
                  td= story.body
                  td= story.userName
        else
            p No registrations yet :(
            
        a(href='/story/add') Add New Story
```

Model

```
//storyModel

let mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Add Story
let storySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    body:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    userName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    } 
}, { timestamps: true });

let Story = module.exports = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
```

Comment: Update - have started getting only one of the views printed when edited the home controller to : 
exports.getHome = (req, res) => {
  Story.find()
  Ask.find()
  .then((stories, asks) => {
    res.render('home', {stories, asks});
  })
  .catch(() => { res.send('Sorry!'); });
  };

Comment: Trying Promise.all.. but function logic is incorrect --